# XML from XSD error Invalid content was found

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to create an XML file based on an XSD schema definition,The schema definition found in the following link

**[Schema-http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/forms/CompanyIncorporation-v2-6.xsd](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/forms/CompanyIncorporation-v2-6.xsd)**

And my XML is as follows,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CompanyIncorporation xmlns="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v2-1/schema/forms/CompanyIncorporation-v2-6.xsd">
    <CompanyType>BYSHR</CompanyType>
    <CountryOfIncorporation>EW</CountryOfIncorporation>
    <RegisteredOfficeAddress>
    <Premise>38</Premise>
    <Street>Vaughan Road</Street>
    <Thoroughfare>Pentwyn</Thoroughfare>
    <PostTown>Harrow</PostTown>
    <Country>GB-ENG</Country>
    <Postcode>HA1 4EE</Postcode>
    </RegisteredOfficeAddress>
    <Articles>BESPOKE</Articles>
    <RestrictedArticles>false</RestrictedArticles>
    <SameDay>false</SameDay>
    <SameName>false</SameName>
    <NameAuthorisation>false</NameAuthorisation>
    </CompanyIncorporation>
```

But it will create an error when i validating it,

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 15, 18: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 18; 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'SameDay'. One 
of '{"http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk":Appointment}' is expected.
```

[***DEMO***](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=4f516a61-e553-4211-9fc5-2bab45fc2b2a-xsdvalidation#.VBLEm5SSx_Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a few of the requirements.

The document type is `CompanyIncorporationType` which is just a `sequence` of elements. With `sequence`, all the elements in it must be specified, unless `minOccurs` set to 0.

> The schema element `xsd:sequence` defines that the enclosed set of elements should occur in the given order and according to the specified minimum and maximum repetition counts. (The default for both is 1.)

Since the error happens at `<SameDay>`, look at all the (same level) elements defined in the xsd, between `<xs:element name="RestrictedArticles">` and `<xs:element name="SameDay">`

- `<xs:element name="Appointment" maxOccurs="unbounded">` - **REQUIRED**
- `<xs:element name="StatementOfCapital" type="StatementOfCapitalType" minOccurs="0"/>` - **Not Required**
- `<xs:element name="Subscribers" type="SubscriberPersonType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">` - **Not Required**
- `<xs:element name="Guarantors" type="GuarantorType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">` - **Not Required**
- `<xs:element name="Authoriser">` - **REQUIRED**

So...

You are missing two elements `<Appointment>` and `<Authorizer>` before `<SameDay>`

That said, it often helps to have a IDE (or some xml tool) create a xml shema implentation. For instance, with Eclipse, it will create the bare bones minimum skeleton to validate against the xsd.

Here is the file created (by Eclipse), which has the bare minimum for the xml to validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompanyIncorporation ... >
    <CompanyType>PLC</CompanyType>
    <CountryOfIncorporation>EW</CountryOfIncorporation>
    <RegisteredOfficeAddress>RegisteredOfficeAddress</RegisteredOfficeAddress>
    <Appointment>
        <Authentication>Authentication</Authentication>
        <Authentication>Authentication</Authentication>
        <Authentication>Authentication</Authentication>
        <Director />
    </Appointment>
    <Authoriser>
        <Agent>
            <Person>Person</Person>
            <Authentication />
            <Authentication />
            <Authentication />
            <Address>Address</Address>
        </Agent>
    </Authoriser>
    <SameDay>true</SameDay>
</CompanyIncorporation>
```

---

**UPDATE**

To explain the elements you see inside the `<Appointment>` and `<Authoriser>`:

**`<Appointment>`**

```
<xs:element name="Appointment" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Proposed officers</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Authentication" type="PersonalAttributeType" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="Director">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="DirectorAppointmentType"/>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Secretary" type="SecretaryAppointmentType"/>
                <xs:element name="Member" type="MemberAppointmentType"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

You can see the `<Appointment>` has a `sequence` - `<Authentication>` exactly three times, **and** a `choice`, between `<Director>`, `<Secretary>`, or `<Member>`. You will have to sort through the xsd to actually see the requirements for the types of those elements

**`<Authoriser>`**

```
<xs:element name="Authoriser">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Agent" type="AgentType">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Solicitor" type="AuthoriserType">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Member" type="AuthoriserType">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Subscribers">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Subscriber" type="AuthoriserType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

You can see `<Authoriser>` requires a **single** choice of either `<Agent>`, `<Member>`, `<Solicitor>`, or `<Subscriber>`. You will have to sort through the xsd to actually see the requirements for the types of those elements